# Array full of dates in Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I have a collection full of dates, but I want them to be ordered in the

correct order, how can that be done? for example I have a spinner it shows a

all the dates but not in order.

```
    String[] dates = {      
                    "Sun, Dec 2, 9:00 AM",
                    "Sun, Dec 2, 10:30 AM",
                    "Sun, Dec 2, 12:00 PM",
                    "Sun, Dec 2, 1:30 PM",
                    "Sun, Dec 2, 3:00 PM",

                    "Mon, Dec 3, 9:00 AM",
                    "Mon, Dec 3, 10:30 AM",
                    "Mon, Dec 3, 12:00 PM",
                    "Mon, Dec 3, 1:30 PM",
                    "Mon, Dec 3, 3:00 PM",

                    "Tue, Dec 4, 9:00 AM",
                    "Tue, Dec 4, 10:30 AM",
                    "Tue, Dec 4, 12:00 PM",
                    "Tue, Dec 4, 1:30 PM",
                    "Tue, Dec 4, 3:00 PM"

                    };

            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(dates));


            HashMap<String, String> datesMap = new HashMap<>();
            for (String date : list) {
                datesMap.put("Date", date);
                db.collection("BookingDates").document().set(datesMap);
            }
```

Comment: Not to be condescending, but you really need to get a grasp of the fundamentals and learn more about the available data structures and how they work. Any answer to your issue would exceed the scope of what SO is trying to do. Eg.: a `HashMap` forbids multiple entries with the same `Key`...which is what you are doing with  `datesMap.put("Date", date);`. :: That said, have a look at the `SortedMap` data structure.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to retrieve the data from the Firestore in the same order as in the array. The code above inserts that data into the Firstore, but when I retrieve it's not the same order. Question do you know how Firestore works regarding the HashMap?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would suggest saving them to Firestore in Unix Epoch format, and since this is a number that increases constantly, you can order it easily as needed, and then after ordering, you can transform it to human readable with date functions.

Comment: This is a comment based on the OP's problem, but does not provide a real answer. I believe the question does not warrant an answer. I recommend that you either provide a real solution or remove this post...otherwise I will downvote this.

Comment: don't be difficult Barns, it's about helping the newbies, but downvote me if it makes you feel so hot

Comment: Which is why I didn't downvote, but instead indicated that I did not believe that your "answer" provided a solution and suggested that you edit your post to provide a "real solution". But apparently, someone (not the OP) finds your suggestion worthy of an upvote...So, who am I to judge. But, in all honesty the OP has difficulty with basic data structures, do you really think that they will understand how to implement your suggestion? You didn't even address the errors in the code posted in the OP? Besides, it is -10°C where I am--anything to help me "feel hot"  is worth a try.

Comment: Which is precisely why I told him the correct approach to solve this, he/she should read the docs to figure it out from there. Some people have specific problems and some people need more general guidance, that doesn't make them unworthy, but anyway it was cool chatting with you, see you on the next question